# How do I check a boolean string array list for a valid response in android?

Tags: android, arrays

I'm writing a text based game where movement is dictated by typing "go left," "go right," etc.  I have a Boolean Array List with the valid commands, and I want to compare what the user types to the members in the array.  The code I have rejects all commands as invalid.  I believe it's because I'm returning false, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I'm very new to this, so any and all help is appreciated.

```
  private boolean validCommand() {

    ArrayList<Boolean> validCommand = new ArrayList<>();
    validCommand.add(Boolean.valueOf("go left"));
    validCommand.add(Boolean.valueOf("go right"));
    validCommand.add(Boolean.valueOf("go straight"));
    validCommand.add(Boolean.valueOf("go back"));

    for (boolean checkCommand : validCommand) {
        if (typeCommand.getText().toString().equals(checkCommand))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

typeCommand is just the EditText the user types their command in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to use ArrayList<**Boolean**>. you have to use ArrayList<**String**>.
Because you want to compare String to String.

```
private boolean validCommand() {

    List<String> validCommand = new ArrayList<>();
    validCommand.add("go left");
    validCommand.add("go right");
    validCommand.add("go straight");
    validCommand.add("go back");

    // List#contains() will return true if List contains arg, or false not.
    return validCommand.contains(typeCommand.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks a bunch!  I had a similar statement earlier, only I used validCommand.equals(...) instead of .contains.  I thought maybe a Boolean array list would be better, but I was overthinking it.

Comment: yep!! enjoy coding!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean.valueOf(String s)` returns the boolean value of the string, ie "true" would return true. If you have random string, like "go left", it will return false. So if validity is your concern, I would change the array to an array of strings instead and compare the array string with what was typed. If the comparison returns true then you have a valid command.